# Set tintColor for just one tabBarItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to set a tintColor to only one tabBarItem of my tab bar.

Currently, I have :

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = darkGrey
self.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = grey
```

I have 5 tabBarItems (without text) in my Tab Bar and I would like to set the first one in blue when the item is selected.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set it individually for each tabBarItem.
You can change the color of the tab bar for a specific tab by putting this code on the viewDidLoad().

```
//setting your tabBarItem to blue when selected
self.tabBarItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue()], for:.selected)
```

Comment: hmm, if you're using images, i think it may be easier for you to change the asset colors instead of overriding them programmatically and render as original image

Answer (score 3):

If you only change tint color of particular tab then this will be helpful.

```
var tab1 : UITabBarItem = self.tabBar.items![0] as UITabBarItem
tab1.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.gray], for: .normal)

//For Image
tab1.image = UIImage(named: "imageName")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Comment: Why do you create tab1 if you don't use it ?

Comment: @Kevinb  Clearly his intention was to set tab1.tintColor

Comment: I think there is no option `tintColor` for `TabBarItem`. Its there for `TabBar`

Answer (score 1):

Select the UITabbarItem and add a run-time attribute 'selectedImage', select Type as 'Image' and give the name of your image as its value.

[image]

Or By code.

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *targetTabBarItem = [[tabbar items] objectAtIndex:0]; // 
whichever tab-item
UIImage *selectedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name-of-selected-
image.png"];
[targetTabBarItem setSelectedImage:selectedIcon];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can edit in the storyboard
**Image tint** is the color of the **selected** icons
**Background** is the color of the tab bar
**Tint** is the color of the icons

Pls check image below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jnwy.png

Comment: I said that I want that tint color for JUST ONE tab bar item

Comment: dont be angry :) try this . 
 **`override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
  }`**

Answer (score 1):

Here is the another way:

```
self.tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.red
let tabSelected = self.tabBar.selectedItem!
tabSelected.selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "second")
```

Answer (score 0):

My original code

tabaritem.image=UIImage(named: imageName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

I changed **alwaysOriginal to automatic** and it worked for me

tabaritem.image=UIImage(named: imageName)?.withRenderingMode(.automatic)